# URLClassLoader Memory Leak Java

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, urlclassloader

I have been going through a lot of `URLClassLoader` Memory leak solutions on the internet, but I haven't found any fully working code and precise solution. The closest to a solution I found was [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/classloaderlocal-how-avoid)

Any fully functional code or link to it, which uses WeakHashMap() or any other definite way of eliminating memory leak problem on multiple redeploys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the dependency of class loader leak preventer in your build path.
maven dependency for this is :

```
<!-- For Classloader leak protection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.jiderhamn</groupId>
            <artifactId>classloader-leak-prevention</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: you may upgrade it with latest version.