# Suddenly Eden space and Old space becomes full

Tags: java, garbage-collection

The Jboss (6) was running OK for about a month and recently got an exception **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC Overhead limit exceeded.** .
I have been collecting jstat results (every 30 secs) from last 20 days and it looked all fine. Recent jstat results show sudden increase of Eden space and Old space to 100% leading to Allocation failure. 
I am confused if this is a case of memory leak or some other issue.

Following options are used
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=10 -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/jboss/ -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/tmp/jboss/gc.log -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dhibernate.show.sql=false -Dhibernate.batch.size=0 -Dapps.trace.level=10 -Dapplication.caching.interval=60000 -Dhibernate.log.level=INFO

Sample Jstat results below

Thu Nov  2 12:38:27 PET 2017 : PID=13423

S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC

0.00   0.00  18.50  23.50  99.99  31186 6017.911   713 1214.565 7232.476 System.gc()          No GC

Thu Nov  2 12:40:28 PET 2017 : PID=13423

S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC

0.00   0.00  90.07  23.50  99.99  31186 6017.911   713 1214.565 7232.476 System.gc()          No GC

Thu Nov  2 12:40:58 PET 2017 : PID=13423

S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC

82.38   0.00  11.26  23.50  99.99  31187 6018.135   713 1214.565 7232.700 unknown GCCause      No GC

Thu Nov  2 12:41:28 PET 2017 : PID=13423

S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC

0.00  99.97  23.06  38.87  99.99  31188 6018.577   713 1214.565 7233.142 unknown GCCause      No GC

Thu Nov  2 12:41:58 PET 2017 : PID=13423

S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC

0.00   0.00 100.00  93.03  99.95  31193 6020.735   715 1219.246 7239.982 Allocation Failure   unknown GCCause

Thu Nov  2 12:42:28 PET 2017 : PID=13423

S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC

0.00   0.00 100.00 100.00  99.98  31193 6020.735   719 1239.038 7259.773 Allocation Failure   unknown GCCause

Thu Nov  2 12:42:59 PET 2017 : PID=13423

S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC

0.00   0.00 100.00 100.00  99.98  31193 6020.735   725 1269.594 7290.329 Allocation Failure   unknown GCCause

Thu Nov  2 12:43:29 PET 2017 : PID=13423

S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC

0.00   0.00  99.99 100.00  99.90  31193 6020.735   731 1300.619 7321.354 Allocation Failure   unknown GCCause

Thu Nov  2 12:43:59 PET 2017 : PID=13423

S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC

0.00   0.00 100.00 100.00  99.74  31193 6020.735   736 1326.877 7347.613 unknown GCCause      Allocation Failure

Between 12:41:28 to 12:42:28, sudden increase in the utilization can be seen.

Comment: Looks like a memory leak. Evaluate your memory dump against a tool like Eclipse MAT to see which object may cause this.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. i'll try evaluating memory dump. 
However, my worry is, if it is memory leak, how come the heap becomes full (from 38% to 100%) within a minute. I mean, shouldn't it be a gradual increase of heap over a period of time.

Comment: That sounds exactly as a memory leak

Comment: Hi,
Just another query, I was analyzing this memory dump. In that, one of the major suspect as per Eclipse MAT is "java.net.URLClassLoader". I wanted to understand, when would the objects created using URLClassLoader be garbage collected.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30565831/1065197) can help you.